# Jquery Model Popup

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Dear Expert i have a aspx apge in which i want to open a Jquery modelpop up having some information like Username and pasword and model pop up also having two button like login and cancle when i click login then i want to redirect to user to his dashbord i want to use this in aspx page and cs page how i will achive this i am new in jquery i don`t know anything about jquery will you please tell me howto do that step wise.

Thanks
Naval Kishor Pandey

Comment: is the below link useful , other let me know i can guide you furthur , i have done lot of similar stuff...

Comment: not much friend but you can get the starting knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naval,

First following this link to create a popup , it has step by step....code

http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/

in this form you can have login and cancel....